# update record from array

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with updating records from an array. When I go to update I am only getting the first digit. For example if the real value is 58 I am only getting the 5 inserted

Below is my code with further explanation below:

```
$bidArr = $tmpArr;

foreach($tmpArr as $key => $val)
{
$sqlEp = "select sum(endpoints_c), account_id1_c as id from accounts_cstm as ac join accounts as a on a.id = ac.id_c 
where account_id1_c ='$val' and (status_c IN ('active','llp')) and deleted='0'";
$rowEp = $db->query($sqlEp);
$recordEp = $db->fetch_row($rowEp);

$bidArr[$key]['sold_ep_c'] = $recordEp[0];

//print "<pre>EP";
//print_r($recordEp);

}

foreach($bidArr as $key => $val)
{

$data['sold_ep_c'] = $val['sold_ep_c'];
$db->query_update(TABLE_ACC, $data, "id_c='".$key."'");
print "<pre>EP";
print_r($key);
print_r($data);
}
```

What is happening is when I uncomment the first print_r I get:

EPArray
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 51067d38

which is right. But if I comment it out and uncomment the second one I get:

51067d38
(
    [sold_ep_c] => 1
)

Why is this stripping the first digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per chat...your arrays aren't initialized.
`$bidArr[$key] = array();` in the first loop!

Comment: Same thing.. Still just getting the first digit.

Comment: When I do that I get some random id instead of the total:

EP4406840a
(
    [sold_ep_c] => 406840a-ca39
)

Comment: Can you print_r($val['sold_ep_c']); ? [within the loop]

Comment: I can print_r($val['sold_ep_c']); but get the first digit only.

Comment: Try print_r($val); (and paste the result)

Comment: 21b7f3cc-807a-228b-c07d-4c69e527fe78

122dad28-c77b-b962-8399-4e32b655cd96

7489412d-7d38-11c0-d7b4-4f9857d5350a

56e0368-9d9e-3647-f79f-4d3f27e61be5

276244db-a93f-e2d8-cf3b-4c868745d1d6

Comment: that's bizarre. for whatever reason, I'm not seeing what is getting changed in between the two blocks of code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13090/discussion-between-ipengineer-and-david)